# Dropdown issues losing value "0" after selection of first

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Below is some code I'm currently working with that populates a second dropdown based on the value of the first dropdown selection.
Everything works as planned except, when I select something in the first dropdown where I have "Select Cat", the Select Cat goes away and my dropdown has only the items from my database. How can I make the Select Cat stay, because without it they do not have to select anything.

```
<div class="right">
        <h5>Process&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<select id="Process" onchange="getProcess(this.value)" name="Process" class='form-control'>
        <option value="">Select Process</option>
<?php

    $sql1 = 'SELECT tblProcess.PID, tblProcess.pName
                FROM tblProcess
                WHERE tblProcess.pActive=1
                ORDER BY tblProcess.pOrder';
    foreach( $stamp->query($sql1) as $row ) {

    echo '<option value="' .$row['PID'].'">  '.$row['pName'].'</option>';
    }
?>
        </select>

        <h5>Category&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<select id="Cat" onchange="getCat(this.value)" name="Cat" class='form-control'>
                       <option value="">Select Cat</option>

        <script type="text/javascript">
                function getProcess(PID)
                {
                    var html = $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "proc_aj.php",
                        data: "PID=" +PID,
                        async: false
                        }).responseText;
                            if(html){
                            $("#Cat").html(html);
                            }
                }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add another placeholder right after your 'cat'-selection.

```
<select id="Process" disabled></select>
```

Put response into 'Process'-selection:

```
if(html){
    $("#Process").html(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. 
I moved the Select Cat into my 
"proc_aj.php" page!

```
<?php

require_once('conn/conn.php');

$sql2 = "SELECT CID, PID, cName from tblCategory where cActive=1 and       PID=".$_REQUEST['PID'];
echo '<option value="">Select Cat</option>';

foreach( $stamp->query($sql2) as $row ) {
            echo'<option value="' .$row['CID'].'">  '.$row['cName'].'</option>';
}



?>
```